# Building against GLIBC for an NDK library

Tags: android, linux, open-source, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am interested in building an open source project and it requires the GNU libraries GLIBC and GLIBM. If I were to cross-compile this under Linux (I am using Ubuntu 11.10 as the host) for a shared (.so), or even a static (.a) object, with the ARMv7-a neon architecture, using API-9, as a library to call with Java's JNI, to ultimately compile as an APK for distribution, what steps would one undertake to achieve this outcome?

Given I have tried the Google NDK toolchain (setting $PATH and $CC the hard and easy way according to the documentation), a variety of custom toolchains, the [Code Sourcery toolchain](https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release858) and a toolchain suggested on the [XDA forum using crosstool-ng](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1299962), is it possible to achieve a shared object file that can be called from JNI and has access to the full GLIBC library on a non-rooted Android device?

I have searched for an answer to this and the closest I have come is to build GLIBC and GLIBM locally and copy the relevant object (.o) files and link manually using the NDK's arm-linux-androideabi-ld. The libc.so.6 file from Crosstool-ng and CodeSourcery will not work as the relocations fail (giving error unknown reloc type 19) when calling the library using Java's System.LoadLibarary(). My knowledge of relocations is not the best but from what I have read this would require changes to the /linux/elf.h header file, but I am not sure exactly where to go from there.

I believe from what I have read that it may be possible to make a static executable that has all dependencies resolved when linked but then it would not be possible to package this as an APK file as far as I'm aware.

Surely I can't be the first to want to compile C code against something other than Bionic for the Android platform? There are so many C projects that could be ported to Android and apparently GLIBC has been available on iPhone for quite a while.

Comment: Did u come up with a solution? If so, kindly let me know.

Comment: No I didn't, unfortunately, but it looks like it is possible with a lot of work: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163765/cross-compiling-glibc-for-my-arm-soc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any low level C library has very tight ties with the OS itself. While Linux and Android may *mostly* be the same thing, they are not. Building against another C library will require said C library to be ported first.

Comment: And, in most cases it's way easier to port the application to a different "standard" C library than porting the C library itself.

Comment: Well, that post is about glib , not glibc. I'd expect glib to be straight forward to port, as it's more or less a normal library.